# How to make PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection work on PhpUnit 6? How to create an alias for DBUnit 3 classes?

Tags: phpunit, dbunit

Unfortunately, I can't use composer in my project.
It uses Zend Framework 1 with thousands of phpUnit tests for PhpUnit 5.
Now I want to port (migrate) them to PhpUnit 6.

Declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd" 
         bootstrap="testbootstrap.php" 
         extensionsDirectory="./extensions">
```

Extension is successfully connectd since --verbosed shows me good message:

```
PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.22 with Xdebug 2.5.5
Configuration: /tests/phpunit/phpunit.xml
Extension:     phpunit/dbunit 3.0.0
```

But when trying to access any method of DbUnit in testbootstrap.php:

```
class_alias('PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\DefaultConnection', 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection');
```

I see an error:

```
PHP Warning:  Class 'PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\DefaultConnection' not found in /tests/phpunit/testbootstrap.php on line 94
Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection' not found in /library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Db/Connection.php on line 44
```

although it works fine for PhpUnit itself:

```
class_alias('PHPUnit\Framework\Test', 'PHPUnit_Framework_Test');
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Comment: Class 'PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\DefaultConnection' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
The problem was that I used DbUnit class mapping before this extension is initialized.
I simply moved it to setUpBeforeClass() in included trait:

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    if (
        method_exists('PHPUnit\Runner\Version', 'id') && version_compare(PHPUnit\Runner\Version::id(), '6', '>=')
    ) {
            class_alias('PHPUnit\DbUnit\Database\DefaultConnection', 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection');
    }
    return parent::setUpBeforeClass();
}
```